# how to set a click listener on individual listpreference items in android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

In my application I would like to set a click listener on the individual preferencelist items in my preference activity, the problem is I can only find out how to set a click listener on the just the main listprefernce itself, is there a way I could set a key to the individual list items so when I set up an OnPreferenceClickListener I can execute some list item specific code?

Answer (score 1):

make sure your preference class `implements` OnPreferenceClickListener and then override the `onPreferenceClick` then just check what preference key was pressed

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    if (preference.getKey().equals("schedulestart")) {
        showDialog(0);
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("schedulestop")) {
        showDialog(1);
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("priority")) {

        getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("unreadcount", 0).commit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: so should I use the individual array names as the key here?

Comment: yes there is an android value `android:key` that you set the key name in the xml

Answer (score 1):

This question is relatively ancient, but I was looking to do a similar thing -- specifically get a hook in whenever any ListPreference item is clicked.  Things like onSharedPreferenceChanged did not work for me because I need to do something even when the currently selected ListPreference is clicked.  I'm not sure I understand the other answer here as solving the problem.  My googling hasn't uncovered any other solutions.

I went along with extending ListPreference and overriding onDialogClosed().  The ListPreference source code for onDialogClosed is

```
    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult && mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0 && mEntryValues != null) {
            String value = mEntryValues[mClickedDialogEntryIndex].toString();
            if (callChangeListener(value)) {
                setValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I created a working interface to send the value of the selected list item in my new ListPreference and then overrode onDialogClosed:

```
public class MyListPreference extends ListPreference {

    private ListItemClickListener mListItemClickListener;

...

    public void setOnListItemClickListener(ListItemClickListener listener) {
        mListItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ListItemClickListener {
        public void onListItemClick(String value);
    }
...

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

        if (positiveResult && getEntryValues() != null && mListItemClickListener != null) {
            String value = getValue();
            mListItemClickListener.onListItemClick(value);
        }
    }
```

Then, in your settings activity (or wherever you are using the new ListPreference), just hook it in:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        MyListPreference listPref = (MyListPreference)
                findPreference(getString(R.string.key_name));
        listPref.setOnListItemClickListener(this);    
    }

    ...
    public void onListItemClick(String value) { 
    // Do something
    }
```

This works for my purposes.

Comment: `androidx` does not provide `onDialogClosed`